# react dropzone, limiting the number of pics uploaded, and giving an error message when limit exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I am using react dropzone, to upload images, but i want to limit the number of images uploaded to 6 only. How do i achieve this?anything greater that 6 should give a error message pop up

https://codesandbox.io/s/3qpokv2xv1

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'react-dropzone-component/styles/filepicker.css';
import 'dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css';

import DropUploader from './DropUploader';
import './styles.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DropUploader
        onUpload={file => console.log(file)}
        onRemove={file => console.log(file)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the following config:

```
const djsConfig = {
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  maxFiles: 6
};
```

Comment: sorry, I am confused, where do i need to add this

Comment: In the codesandbox.io link that you've mentioned. You have a file: 'DropUploader.js', inside it you should add the maxFiles proprety inside the jssConfig object.